# Waiting for Web Request Results in HTML <script> Tag

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

An application I'm writing has the following requirement:

I need to implement a fetch request within a  tag, but I need to wait for the results of the request before the rest of the page is loaded? The goal is to run window.stop() if the results match a certain value, but allow the page to fully load if the results don't match the specified value.

Is there any way to implement this?

I know this is not an efficient way to load the page, and it will make the page load slower, but that is not a concern for the current application.

Comment: I don't think you can stop the browser  from loading the page once the response containing it has been sent, however it may be possible to only send your script first, then if the script passes, ajax load the rest of the page.

Comment: You can load the page content normally, but hide  page's content, and if your verification process fails, you can make a change to the page content, for example with an error message ... for example :  `<body><div class='app' style='display:none;'></div><div class='Loader'>Loading.....</div></body>`

Comment: @Mido That makes sense, but I’d like to keep the content completely unavailable to the end user unless the response matches a certain value. Using window.stop() would prevent anything after the script tag from losing which would keep the user from seeing any of the content on the page.

Comment: @micma You can save the page content in a local variable
 Inside a function, I have answered your question with an example of what I meant

Answer (score 0):

I don't think http requests can be controlled directly through DOMJS, but you can use the following method to do what you want:

The method simply saves the content of the page to a local variable inside the function, and then displays it when you are done with your verification.

This Function Was Be called When Your Browser displayed the basic html content :

```
   function CheckPageContent(){
      var appData = document.querySelector("#AppData");
      var htmlContent = appData.innerHTML
      appData.innerHTML = "";
      setTimeout(function(){
        appData.innerHTML = htmlContent;
        appData.style.display = 'block';
        document.querySelector("#Loader").style.display = 'none';
      },3000);
    }
```

Your page must be have this structure :

```
<body>
    <div id="AppData" style="display:none">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_girl.jpg">
       <br>
    Hello 1Worled!


  </div>
    <div id="Loader">Loading......</div>

</body>
    <script>
        CheckPageContent();
    </script>
```

If you want how the method works, then you must first understand how the browser works when you request a page

Until everything is clear, the browser when you request a page, the browser downloads only the hypertext (html) for this page, and then displays it on the page.
In the event that the hypertext contains external files, the browser downloads them separately from the main page.
For example, if the requested page contains this crown

After viewing the basic hypertext, the browser will download the bootstarp file and then normalize it to the already displayed html text .... and so on with the images and other files ....